# Replace element in an unordered map

Tags: c++

I have a unordered map with an enum in key and a shared_ptr in content.

When I initialize my map, I use emplace like this :

```
this->_menu.emplace(BINDINGS, std::shared_ptr<AMenu>(new BindingMenu("Player 1"));
```

But I would like to know if I can replace (at the same place), with another BindingMenu object :

```
std::shared_ptr<AMenu>(new BindingMenu("Player 2")
```

Thanks

Comment: `this->_menu[BINDINGS] = std::make_shared<BindingMenu>("Player 2");` ?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Don't begin identifiers with underscores. If you want to distinguish members from locals or parameters then use `m_menu` or `mMenu`. Use of `this` is optional except when accessing members of a templated base class. Use `std::make_shared<BindingMenu>("Player 2");` to create a `std::shared_ptr<BindingMenu>`

Comment: Why it's better with "m" before ? for "member" ?

Comment: Yes, "m" is for "member". You don't have to prepend "m" but it's a common convention among C++ developers.

Comment: The underscore as prefix is to avoid to break those rules [what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: You need to delete the old value or you will leak.

Comment: @stark: auto-magically done thanks to smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jarod42 mentioned, you can access an element in a map using the operator[]

```
this->_menu[BINDINGS] = std::shared_ptr<AMenu>(new BindingMenu("Player 2"));
```

If the element you are trying to access didn't exist yet, it will be created.

More information here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/